# Arch & DWM weird font

Tags: arch-linux, fonts, dwm

I'm a Arch and DWM newb and I can't figure out why text is displayed so weird on my screen (see screenshot).
Can someone help me with this?[image]

Comment: Is this weird text shown only on your terminal emulator, `kitty` or to other applications also? You probably need to set the font that `kitty` uses. Also, do you use any japanese, chinese, arabic locale? It seems like wide multibyte unicode is used, for characters on such locales and encodings.

Comment: @Krackout I'm using en_US.UTF8 and it's weird in all applications, not only kitty. How would I set the font for kitty?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow managed to fix it by installing chromium...

Comment: Probably some fonts were installed as dependencies.